# Is there a way to count the number of assertions in TestNG?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testng, assertions

Actually the title includes the question.

I would like to know how many assertions have been evaluated in the tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [aspectj](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/) for this. If you define a pointcut that matches with assert calls, you can keep a counter in an aspect and report that counter after the tests have run.

If you make the pointcut finegrained enough, you could count assertTrue() different from assertEquals(), etc.. if you would want that.

Comment: I would rather do this without another dependency if it is possible.

Comment: I accept this answer, because there is no other way right now.

Comment: Actually, you could create extend the Assert class and override the assert methods in order to provide the counting for each of them. AspectJ is cleaner, of course, it you want it to be a cross-cutting characteristic.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no.

What you can do is use your own asserts and maintain a counter there.